# PostgreSQL очистка места

Tags: postgresql, администрирование

Удалил из постгреса несколько своих баз (drop database). Однако место на машине не освободилось. Логично было бы сделать вакуум, но сами базы то уже удалены.
Как поступить и освободить место?
Стоит постгрес 13-й версии

Comment: посмотрите на уровне файловой системы чем действительно занято место. drop database удаляет все файлы этой базы из файловой системы сразу.

Comment: Благодарю. В принципе нашел косяк. Очень много валов скопилось. Почитал старые. Плюс я это делал всё на кластере патрони. Реинит кластера решил проблему